# How mysql sends big result from SELECT query?

Tags: mysql

My mysql-driver uses binary protocol for directly interaction with mysql.
And i want know, how often mysql sends packets with results.

There is 2 ways:

1. Mysql accumulate some results in the memory, and sends them at one time.
2. Mysql sends results every time when they are available.

Could you help me determine to this situation ? I need know concrete answer on this question based on sources of MySQL or concrete phrase from manual

May MySQL has some  settings for buffer of response ?

Thanks.

Comment: It probably depends on the driver and the settings.

Comment: As i said, i have directed connection with mysql. This mysql-driver is part of my code, so i can change and manage it as i want. My point is just only mysql-server side. How mysql sends packets of results.

Comment: You probably are using some derivate of the c api. The usual way to retrieve results is row-wise: you send a request to mysql server to fetch the next (=one) row of the result set, and the server will send a packet back (same logic for all other commands). Mysql will store the results (unless you send e.g. a request to free the result). Have a look at [C API Function Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-function-overview.html), your driver will probably have similar functions.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I'm curious how you could have written your own driver without knowing these details already.

Answer (score 0):

The client-server protocol is documented in [Chapter 14](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html) of the MySQL documentation.

The commands used to send a query and fetch results are documented in the [Command Phase](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/command-phase.html). Specific to your question, the command to fetch results is [COM_STMT_FETCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-stmt-fetch.html#packet-COM_STMT_FETCH). The parameters to this command are the statement ID of a previously prepared statement, and the number of rows to fetch. The documentation doesn't say so explicitly, but I presume that it doesn't return any more rows than are requested. So it sends results `N` at a time, where `N` is the parameter to this command.